# Using SailsJS, is there a way to Model.watch() based on a certain value in the records?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

For instance, if I have a model called Tasklist and do the following:

`io.socket.get('/tasklist','',function(data,res){
  // do stuff here
})`

I use a custom Controller Action, so the client will receive all the current tasks in the list **where the GROUP field matches the groups the user belongs to**.  Plus, it subscribes to each record so it will receive notifications of changes.  However, if I Tasklist.watch(req), the client(s) will get notified & subscribed to EVERY new record, not just the one's that match the user's groups.

I only want the user to receive records that they are allowed to see.  I realized I could just ignore those message on the client, but the frames would still show up in the chrome debugging tools, and client side ignoring is not the right way.  Is there a preferred or built-in way to do this with Sails?  From the documentation and searching SO, I haven't found anything specific to this.

I'll try this when I'm back at my computer...

```
// for each group user is a member of...
sails.sockets.join(req, 'tasklist:'+group, cb);

// for each POST/CREATE...
sails.sockets.broadcast('tasklist:'+group, 'CREATED', taskID)

// The clients will
io.socket.get('/tasklist/'+taskID)
for the record details and will then be subscribed
```

If theres a better way than making each client subscribe to the individual records, perhaps using addRoomMembersToRooms that would be great.  I just don't know the room name format Sails uses/generates for things like Tasklist.subscribe()

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I figured it out, so hopefully, this will help someone else in the future.

I used `console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms)` in node to find the names of the rooms, and the naming convention is as such: (382 is a record ID)

```js
sails_model_tasklist_382:update  // notices about updates to record 382
sails_model_tasklist_382:destroy // notices about record 382 being deleted
sails_model_tasklist_382:message // misc msgs you may send about record 382

sails_model_create_tasklist:     // EVERY record addeded to this table/view 
                                 // whether you should get them or not
```

I have forgone `Tasklist.PublishCreate()` and instead use my own channels/rooms with a similar naming convention: `sails_model_create_tasklist:group_1`, and have created my own `groupPublishCreate()` function.

At the end of the TasklistController's `find` function (not `findOne`), I subscribe that req/socket to my custom group room instead of using `.watch()`; it's also a one-liner, so not too bad.

In the controller's `create` function I nested a groupPublishCreate function that uses `sails.sockets.addRoomMembersToRooms` to subscribe everyone in my custom room to the `:update`, `:destroy`, and `:message` rooms for the new record that was added.

From this point forward, they'll get updates when this record changes, but they still need to get a created message-- they don't know a new record was added just yet.  Now I simply broadcast the new record to my custom room using the same data format Sails uses, so (to the client) it looks just like a normal Sails 'created' message.

#### In the controller's FIND action

```js
// We could use a loop if result.taskGroup was a collection/array
// It's a one-liner, no more difficult than Tasklist.watch(req)
sails.sockets.join(req, 'sails_model_create_tasklist:group_' + result.taskGroup)

// Just to be concise...
// To disable updates (eg: if a user slides a live-update toggle)
// This wouldn't actually go here, put it in the right route
sails.sockets.leave(req, 'sails_model_create_tasklist:group_' + groupIdSentByClient)
```

#### In the controller's CREATE action

```js
groupPublishCreate('tasklist', result.taskGroup, result)

function groupPublishCreate(modelIdentity, groupID, record) {
  var bcastRoom = 'sails_model_create_' + modelIdentity + ':group_' + groupID
  var subscribeToTheseChannels = [
    'sails_model_' + modelIdentity + '_' + record.id + ':update',
    'sails_model_' + modelIdentity + '_' + record.id + ':destroy',
    'sails_model_' + modelIdentity + '_' + record.id + ':message'
  ]

  sails.sockets.addRoomMembersToRooms(
    bcastRoom,
    subscribeToTheseChannels,
    function (err) {
      // error handler goes here
    }
  )

  sails.sockets.broadcast(
    bcastRoom,
    modelIdentity,
    {verb: 'created', data: record, id: record.id}
  )
}
```

#### On the client

```js
// The incoming frame looks like this (copied from chrome's Network dev tab)
42["tasklist",{"verb":"created","data":{"msg":"this is a test","id":437},"id":437}]
// The incoming frame of a Sails PublishCreate() message 
42["tasklist",{"verb":"created","data":{"msg":"this is a test","id":437},"id":437}]
// As you can see, they are identical, and can be parsed the same way

io.socket.on('tasklist',function(msg){
  // The CUD is CRUD... R is the Response to a GET
  if (msg.verb === 'created') insertNewTask(msg.data)
  if (msg.verb === 'updated') updateTaskList(msg.data)
  if (msg.verb === 'destroyed') removeTask(msg.id)
})
```

#### Not related, but I did this to use Sails as a jQuery extension

```js
jQuerySails = {
  extend: function () {
    $.API = io.socket
    if ($.API) {
      return ({success: '$.API is available for use'})
    } else {
      return ({error: 'Sails was not extended to $.API'})
    }
  },
  remove: function () {
    delete $.API
    if (!$.API) {
      return ({success: '$.API has been removed'})
    } else {
      return ({error: '$.API is still available for use'})
    }
  }
}

console.log(jQuerySails.extend())

$.API.on('tasklist',function(msg){
  // The CUD is CRUD... R is the Response to a GET
  if (msg.verb === 'created') insertNewTask(msg.data)
  if (msg.verb === 'updated') updateTaskList(msg.data)
  if (msg.verb === 'destroyed') removeTask(msg.id)
})
```